# Delete a duplicate from an array but keep a specific duplicate based on condition

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array `[[1, nil, nil], [1, 123, nil]]` in which I am calling `uniq` on to remove duplicates based on the first value. However I want to specifically keep the duplicate that does not have `nil` for the second value (`123` in this case)

`my_array.uniq { |arr| arr.first.id }`

Might return `[[1, nil, nil]]` but I want to ensure it returns `[[1, 123, nil]]`. Is there any way to do this rails style with `uniq`?

As thinkgruen stated below, I'm not too concerned with the case where there are 3 duplicates, since calling `uniq` again without the special condition is an option.

Comment: what would happen if the third element is `[1, 123, nil]` again? from what i understood, it will return `[[1, 123, nil], [1, 123, nil]]` but I think it's important to cover this case in your question as well.

Comment: Good point, there might be a better way but at the very least I can add another call to `uniq` without the condition.

Comment: I think the posted solution from cschroed is fine. because to use `uniq` the elements would have to be in order already, so that the first one is the one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to break this into multiple steps.

```rb
my_array = [[1, nil, nil], [1, 123, nil]]

# Group them
grouped = my_array.group_by(&:first)

# Decide which to keep
grouped.values.map do |group|
  # Detect one where the 2nd value isn't nil.  Otherwise take the first.
  group.detect { |object| !object[1].nil? } || group.first
end

 => [[1, 123, nil]]
```